# I am trying to do a quantized mobilenet model to tensorflow lite model, but run into an error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

First I have download a quantized model from Mobilenet. It is contained in Mobilenet_v1_1.0_224. Then I did the following

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco \
> --input_files=Sample/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/quantized_graph.pb \
> --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE \
> --output_file=Sample/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/quantized_graph.tflite --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
> --input_shape=1,224,224,3 \
> --input_array=input \
> --output_array=MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1 \
> --mean_value=128 \
> --std_value=127
```

The following is the summary of the graph

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph --in_graph=Sample/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/quantized_graph.pb
Found 1 possible inputs: (name=input, type=float(1), shape=[1,224,224,3]) 
No variables spotted.
Found 1 possible outputs: (name=MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1, op=Reshape) 
Found 4227041 (4.23M) const parameters, 0 (0) variable parameters, and 0 control_edges
Op types used: 91 Const, 27 Add, 27 Relu6, 15 Conv2D, 13 DepthwiseConv2dNative, 13 Mul, 10 Dequantize, 2 Reshape, 1 Identity, 1 Placeholder, 1 BiasAdd, 1 AvgPool, 1 Softmax, 1 Squeeze
To use with tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model try these arguments:
bazel run tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model -- --graph=Sample/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/quantized_graph.pb --show_flops --input_layer=input --input_layer_type=float --input_layer_shape=1,224,224,3 --output_layer=MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

So by doing the conversion, I ran into the following error

> 2018-03-01 23:12:03.353786: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1172] Converting
>   unsupported operation: Dequantize 2018-03-01 23:12:03.354513: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1172] Converting
>   unsupported operation: Dequantize 2018-03-01 23:12:03.355177: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1172] Converting
>   unsupported operation: Dequantize 2018-03-01 23:12:03.355556: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1172] Converting
>   unsupported operation: Dequantize 2018-03-01 23:12:03.355921: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1172] Converting
>   unsupported operation: Dequantize 2018-03-01 23:12:03.356281: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1172] Converting
>   unsupported operation: Dequantize 2018-03-01 23:12:03.356632: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1172] Converting
>   unsupported operation: Dequantize 2018-03-01 23:12:03.357540: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1172] Converting
>   unsupported operation: Dequantize 2018-03-01 23:12:03.358776: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1172] Converting
>   unsupported operation: Dequantize 2018-03-01 23:12:03.360448: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1172] Converting
>   unsupported operation: Dequantize 2018-03-01 23:12:03.366319: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39]
>   Before Removing unused ops: 140 operators, 232 arrays (0 quantized)
>   2018-03-01 23:12:03.371405: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39]
>   Before general graph transformations: 140 operators, 232 arrays (0
>   quantized) 2018-03-01 23:12:03.374916: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39]
>   After general graph transformations pass 1: 63 operators, 152 arrays
>   (1 quantized) 2018-03-01 23:12:03.376325: I
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39]
>   Before pre-quantization graph transformations: 63 operators, 152
>   arrays (1 quantized) 2018-03-01 23:12:03.377492: F
>   tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:1272] Array
>   MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/Relu6, which is an input to the
>   DepthwiseConv operator producing the output array
>   MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/Relu6, is lacking min/max
>   data, which is necessary for quantization. Either target a
>   non-quantized output format, or change the input graph to contain
>   min/max information, or pass --default_ranges_min= and
>   --default_ranges_max= if you do not care about the accuracy of results.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be pointing to an old TensorFlow quantized mobilenet model.

We have updated quantized mobilenet models available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md). The specific link for your depth multiplier of 1.0 and image size of 224 is [this](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/mobilenet_v1_2018_02_22/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tgz).

These tar files also come with the already converted TFLite flatbuffer model as well.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! I wonder what should be the values need to be passed into TensorFlow lite converter? Any difference from what my demonstration code up on the top?

Comment: Yes, you need --mean_value=127.5 and --std_value=127.5. This is a function of the preprocessing used for the images when training the model. If you don't want to mess with conversion you can use the already converter FlatBuffer. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Suharshs, I am trying to do post training quantization with Mobilenet V1, but facing some issues, can you please have a look here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869149/post-training-quantization-for-mobilenet-v1-not-working?noredirect=1#comment102198662_57869149